# What is DRAM atom size? Does it have any relation to the channel size?

Tags: memory, ram, dram

I have seen that the channel size is in bits (64b/128b) which I understand is the amount of data one channel can transfer at an edge. But I see that the atom size is in Bytes. So does an atom of transfer take multiple dram transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom is the smallest amount of data that can be transferred to/from the DRAM. It is very common for ram modules these days to have a burst length of 8 which means that every time data is requested from the module, instead of just transferring 64bits(which is the channel width) it transfers 64bitsx8 bursts of data. Thus  making the total data transferred at each request = 64Bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Atom size is the smallest addressable unit for writes.

If your CPU has a "write byte" instruction, it needs to be able to change a single byte while leaving the other bytes in the same word unaffected. If the RAM provides an atom size of one byte or smaller, this is a single access, where the unmodified bytes are masked out. If the atom size is larger, then a byte write can be implemented only as a read-modify-write sequence.

In the C standard, there is a group of integer types, `int8_fast_t`, `int16_fast_t` etc. that are at least 8, 16, ... bits wide and will never be smaller than the target architecture's atom size, so data structures using these have enough padding to keep each variable individually addressible.

For reading memory, this is less relevant as the reader can simply discard any data it is not interested in, because reading a word takes the same amount of time as reading a single byte.